# Upper bound on maximal number of indepednent sets in a connected graph $G$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple connected graph on $n$ vertices. I need to show that the number of vertex indepednent subsets in $V(G)$ is no bigger than $2^{n-1}+1$. While I realize there may be better bounds I am probably expected to solve this one using basic graph theory and combinatorical tools. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Could you show your approach so far?

Comment: Well first thing I tried to do was find the smallest connected graph in which there would be the most independent sets (since it's connected and has the least number of edges),  I found that to be the line graph with $n-1$ edges. Then I tried counting the number of possible vertices inside a set of size $k$ for different sizes, but I wasn't able to find a good way to get to where I want. (and I'm not sure that's even a proper approach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, since the bound is quite relaxed and the inequality strongly suggests a induction method, here we go.

- With n = 1, there are two independent sets, which is true.
- Suppose the inequality is true up to n - 1. Consider a connected graph of n vertices. Pick any spanning tree, and consider a vertex v that is one of its leaf. There are two ways to pick an independent set:

  1. You don't pick v, which leaves you with a connected graph of n - 1 vertices. From hypothesis, there are at most $2^{n - 2} + 1$ independent sets.
  2. You pick v. Let x be the only vertex that is adjacent to v, remove it. You are left with a (possibly not connected) (n - 2)-vertices graph. But clearly there are at most $2^{n - 2}$ sets in a (n - 2)-vertices graph.

Therefore there are at most $2^{n - 2} + 1 + 2^{n - 2} = 2^{n - 1} + 1$ independent sets, which is precisely what we want. So the induction step is completed./.

P/S: If sharing a complete solution is not encouraged, I will rewrite it in a more elusive way :)

Comment: Why there is only one vertex adjacent to $v$ in case 2? That might be tree in the tree, but not in the graph as a whole.

Comment: Because I only consider the spanning tree of the graph.